# Excel Forumla to combine two sets of data based off unique key contained in both data-sets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to figure out how to combine two data-sets based off a unique key that is present in both sets of data.  I need the columns to align based off this key.

The data-sets aren't so large that I can't copy them all into one spreadsheet (but it's thousands of rows).

**Example**

**Data-set 1**

```
Ford        123-abc        10
Chevy       234-def        20
Honda       345-ghi        12
Jeep        456-klm        7
Hyundai     567-nop        22
```

**Data-set 2**

```
123-abc        1/20/2020        yes        
345-ghi        6/15/2020        no         
567-nop        6/30/2020        maybe
```

If I copy Data-set 2 to empty columns on Data-set 1, I get something that looks like this (data does not align):

```
Ford        123-abc        10      123-abc        1/20/2020        yes  
Chevy       234-def        20      345-ghi        6/15/2020        no  
Honda       345-ghi        12      567-nop        6/30/2020        maybe   
Jeep        456-klm        7
Hyundai     567-nop        22
```

I need everything to align based off that key.  Here is what I need it to look like:

```
Ford        123-abc        10      123-abc        1/20/2020        yes 
Chevy       234-def        20
Honda       345-ghi        12      345-ghi        6/15/2020        no
Jeep        456-klm        7
Hyundai     567-nop        22      567-nop        6/30/2020        maybe
```

Anyone have an idea how that's done?

Thanks

Comment: Use VLOOKUP( )?

Comment: I looked at vlookup.  That just looks like it provides a match.    Instead, I need to align two data-sets based off a unique key.. and the data-sets are thousands of rows long.  So I need data-set 2 to move around to match the key from data-set 1.  If vlookup can do that, I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have access to XLOOKUP, you can use this:

```
=XLOOKUP($B5,$A$12:$A$14,$B$12:$C$14,"")
```

[image]

IF you don't have access to XLOOKUP, you can use VLOOKUP, like this:

First formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B5,$A$12:$C$14,2,FALSE),"")
```

Second formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B5,$A$12:$C$14,3,FALSE),"")
```

[image]